# dbExistsTable() in R odbc says table exists when it shouldn't

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-dbi

#### Issue and Expected Result

[Link to Github Issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/286)

I am trying to drop a table in SQL Server 2017. When I inspect the database, it appears as if the table has disappeared. However, according to odbc, the table still exists. In my example, I am writing a table to a default schema. I then copy the table from default schema into a new table in a new schema. I then drop the table in the default schema. When I run `dbExistsTable()`, it returns TRUE, though.

#### Server

SQL Server 2017

#### Reproducible Example

```r
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
dbExecute(con, "SELECT * INTO [schema].iris FROM iris")
dbExecute(con, "DROP TABLE iris")

dbExistsTable(con, "iris") # returns TRUE, should be FALSE
dbListTables(con) # iris appears here, it should not appear here
```

#### EDIT 1

I will note this error does not appear in the following example leading me to believe something is happening when the table is being copied into another schema.

```r
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
dbExecute(con, "SELECT * INTO iris2 FROM iris")
dbExecute(con, "DROP TABLE iris")

dbExistsTable(con, "iris") # <- returns false as expected
dbListTables(con) # <- iris table does not appear here
```

#### EDIT 2

After dropping the newly created table in the non-default schema, the issue is resolved. This behavior, though, is wrong. I should have to specify in dbExistsTable() the schema name to find that the table exists, no?

Session Info

```r
devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS          
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2019-06-18                  

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 bit           1.1-14  2018-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 bit64         0.9-7   2017-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 blob          1.1.1   2018-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 colorspace    1.4-1   2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 DBI         * 1.0.0   2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 dbplyr      * 1.4.2   2019-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 devtools      2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 digest        0.6.19  2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 dplyr       * 0.8.1   2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 forcats     * 0.4.0   2019-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fs            1.3.1   2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ggplot2     * 3.2.0   2019-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 here        * 0.1     2017-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 hms           0.4.2   2018-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 knitr         1.23    2019-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 lazyeval      0.2.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 odbc        * 1.1.6   2018-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pillar        1.4.1   2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 processx      3.3.1   2019-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 purrr       * 0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 readr       * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rmarkdown   * 1.13    2019-05-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 scales        1.0.0   2018-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tibble        2.1.3   2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tidyr       * 0.8.3   2019-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 usethis       1.5.0   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xfun          0.7     2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that dbExistsTable() is doing something similar to "*Select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'iris'*" under the covers, which would find *[schema].iris* and return true, whether or not *[default].iris* has been deleted.

Comment: I mean it most definitely is. However, this is problematic behaviour because if I want to write a table to a different schema with the same name, I cannot. So I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: One option is a roll-your-own "myExistsTable" that takes two parameters - one for the table name and one for the schema name. Internally you'd do something like "Select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema = @parmeter1 and table_name = @parameter2"